# Mule ForEach Example with File Endpoint

Tags: mule

I'm trying to write a simple Mule Flow that watches a directory for files, then SFTP's them to a final destination.  If there are large amounts of files the SFTPs should be batched up in groups of 10.

Here's my XML

```
<flow name="FileTransferUtilFlow1" doc:name="FileTransferUtilFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="${source.dropbox.dir}"
        moveToDirectory="${completed.dir}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File">
        <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.txt"
            caseSensitive="true" />
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <async processingStrategy="Queued_Asynchronous_Processing_Strategy"
        doc:name="Async">
        <foreach doc:name="Foreach" batchSize="10">
            <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
                host="192.168.1.14" port="22" path="${landing.dir}" user="myID"
                password="xxyyzz" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP"
                outputPattern="#[header:originalFilename]" />
        </foreach>
    </async>
</flow>
```

And here's the Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object "org.mule.transport.file.ReceiverFileInputStream" not of correct type. It must be of type "interface java.lang.Iterable,interface java.util.Iterator,interface org.mule.routing.MessageSequence,interface java.util.Collection"
at org.mule.routing.CollectionSplitter.splitMessageIntoSequence(CollectionSplitter.java:60)
at org.mule.routing.Foreach$CollectionMapSplitter.splitMessageIntoSequence(Foreach.java:250)
at org.mule.routing.outbound.AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.process(AbstractMessageSequenceSplitter.java:60)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ForEach scope, as stated by [the documentation](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3STUDIO/Foreach), is designed to split/aggregate collections. In stead the file endpoint polls each file from a directory and create a message out of it.

To achieve you goal you need to introduce some explicit aggregation strategy. The best way would be to use a [Custom Aggregator](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-CustomAggregator)